# Laravel spatie assign role to user not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-permission

I am simply doing what is in the documentation but God knows what the issue is. I have put `use HasRoles;` in my User Model

```
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasRoles;
}
```

but again and again, getting this error:

```
 Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::assignRole()
```

Whenever assigning role in seeder:

```
  use App\Models\User;
  use Illuminate\Database\Seeder; 
  use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;
  use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;

  public function run()
  {
     $role = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first();
     $user = User::where(['email' => 'admin@admin.com', 'password' => 'password']);
     $user->assignRole($role);
  }
```

`givePermissionTo` is also throwing same sort of error. Any idea why this error is coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `assignRole()` on a **model instance**, not a **builder** :

```
public function run()
{
  $role = Role::where('name', 'Admin')->first();
  $user = User::where(['email' => 'admin@admin.com', 'password' => 'password'])->first();
  $user->assignRole($role);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add trait use HasRoles; in your user model.

Import it with use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles; at the top of the user model file.

Answer (score 0):

Had almost same error, but it's sounds like

> Call to undefined method App\Models\User::assignRole()

Like *Muhammad Ibrahim* wrote, I added HasRoles trait and it works! Below code for clue

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, HasRoles, Notifiable;
```